# How access pictures after they have been taken by camera used by other app

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an idea for an android service, and I need to be able to access pictures before they're being taken, to save GPSlocation, moreover, I need also an access to the picture immediately afterwards.

Is there any proper way to do it ?

Comment: Are you still stuck? Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Due to background limitations, you are unable to do this. Starting in Android O, [implicit broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) are no longer delivered to applications, with [a few exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) (which do not include the [photo taken broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE)). If you want to monitor files and photos saved by other apps, you will need to work with that app's content provider (if it has one) or, alternatively, monitor the media folder which you can get via [Context.getExternalMediaDirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalMediaDirs()).